# Primefaces and Liferay, set theme for the entire portal

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay-6, themeroller

I'm developing primefaces portlets on Liferay.

Setting a theme for a portlet seems to be easy. : You include a yourTheme.jar in WebInf/lib, and define :

```
<context-param>  
   <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
   <param-value>yourTheme</param-value>  
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml

But what I would prefer to do, would be setting that theme for all the PrimeFaces portlets, in one central point (like a custom portal theme or some portal property). So that it effects the whole portal, not each individual portlet. What should be the best way to do that ?

Thanx!

I'm Using:
Liferay 6.1.0 ce ga1.
Primefaces 3.5
Jsf 2.1.3

Comment: maybe this can help: http://www.liferay.com/de/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/default-user-public-layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [develop Liferay Themes](http://content.liferay.com/document/Liferay%20Themes.pdf) and deploy them as war files in your application server.

[Create pages](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/managing-pages-in-liferay-portal) and associate your Prime faces portlets with each pages.

Then apply the theme to your pages.

By applying theme to your pages, you can achieve applying theme to your Prime faces portlets.

Comment: Thank you. When I said 'custom theme', I meant "Liferay Themes", so my concern is how to add the pf theme (or some custom themeroller) to the Liferay Theme. I'll try, and let you know

Comment: Sure. Am interested in knowing